# How to search only the difference region's while using ediff command?

Tags: ediff

While viewing diff b/w 2 files using **ediff** command, i want to search for a string only in the difference region. What is the right way to this?

EDIT: added clarification

Comment: What kind of searching? Which "conflict region"? Please elaborate on what you want to do.

Comment: Since lines with differences are marked with overlays, I think https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/isearch-prop.el would be relevant to this task.